# Trying to write a triangle made of asterisk in a txt file, but did not print in the same format in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

My code prints a right triangle of asterisk. I was expect the same triangle to be written in the text file and in same format, but it doesn't appear that way

```
rows = 1
cols = 1

thisfile = open(r'C:\AdarshNamdev\stars.txt', 'w')
while rows <= 10:
    while cols <= (rows + 1):
        star = " * " * cols
        print(star)
        thisfile.write(star)
        cols += 1
    rows += 1

 thisfile.close()
```

What changes are required to get the desired output?

Comment: Thanks @James Z for editing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `.write` does not write a newline. You'll need to add it, like this:

```
thisfile.write(star + '\n')
```